# Filter the desired items in the array and display them

Tags: javascript

I want to use the array methods to find the cheapest food in the menu and display the foods whose price is higher than 10 along with the name and ID in the console. Thank you for your help.

```
let menu = [
    { id: 1, name: "Soda", price: 3.12, size: "4oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 2, name: "Beer", price: 6.50, size: "8oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 3, name: "Margarita", price: 12.99, size: "12oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 4, name: "Pizza", price: 25.10, size: "60oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 5, name: "Kebab", price: 31.48, size: "42oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 6, name: "Berger", price: 23.83, size: "99oz", type: "Food" },
];
```

Comment: Show what you have done so far

Comment: Also, can you show what your expected result is.

Comment: Please reread the [tour] _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_

Answer (score 2):

It's not very complex, just read the array with a FOR loop and filter the data with an IF .. :)

```
var menu = [
    { id: 1, name: "Soda", price: 3.12, size: "4oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 2, name: "Beer", price: 6.50, size: "8oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 3, name: "Margarita", price: 12.99, size: "12oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 4, name: "Pizza", price: 25.10, size: "60oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 5, name: "Kebab", price: 31.48, size: "42oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 6, name: "Berger", price: 23.83, size: "99oz", type: "Food" },
];

var menu2 = [];  // creates a new array to hold the results 
for(var i = 0; menu[i]; i++){
    if(menu[i].price > 10) menu2[menu2.length] = menu[i]; // If an item has a price greater than 10 then I copy it to the new menu 
}

console.log(menu2); // Display the new menu with the filtered data in the console
```